# PHP switch only shows results of first case

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have three dropdowns in a search form. I would like to display the results if only one dropdown option is selected. Right now, the search only works with the first dropdown box selection (in the example, it's $StockType). If I select only an option in the second or third dropdown, no results will be shown. Here is my switch statement:

```
$StockType = $_GET['StockType'];
$make = $_GET['Make'];
$model = $_GET['Model'];


switch (true) {

    case ($StockType):
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'vehicle',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 15,
            'meta_key' => 'StockType', 
            'meta_value' => $StockType
        );
        break;

    case ($make):
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'vehicle',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 15,
            'meta_key' => 'Make', 
            'meta_value' => $Make
        );
        break;

    case ($model):
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'vehicle',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 15,
            'meta_key' => 'Model', 
            'meta_value' => $model
        );
        break;

}
```

Comment: the first time i see switch (true) {}

Comment: I'd suggest using `var_dump($_GET)` to see what the values you're getting are. It looks like `$_GET['StockType'];` is always being set to something.

Comment: Charaf jra, could you explain what is wrong with that?

Comment: @user715564 - I've been using PHP for a long while, and I've never seen it used that way before; but the PHP documentation page says it's a neat shortcut to find the first variable with a value.

Comment: essentially in PHP, switch(a)...case(b) just tests (a == b). So you can perform all sorts of weird tricks with it.

Comment: Just an observation, not sure if it matters for the problem you're facing: `$Make` on the line `'meta_value' => $Make` is undefined because the variable name is lowercase (`$make`) everywhere else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Switch true will work if you use it right. Try this:

```
switch (true) {

case ( !empty($_GET['StockType']) ):
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'vehicle',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'meta_key' => 'StockType', 
        'meta_value' => $StockType
    );
    break;

case ( !empty($_GET['Make']) ):
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'vehicle',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'meta_key' => 'Make', 
        'meta_value' => $make
    );
    break;

case ( !empty($_GET['Model']) ):
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'vehicle',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'meta_key' => 'Model', 
        'meta_value' => $model
    );
    break;
}
```

[Interesting link about the switch(true) method](http://henrysmith.org/blog/switch-true/)

Comment: Sure, but if you're going to do that, why bother with the `switch`?  Just use plain old `if` statements and remove the level of nesting.

Comment: @IanMcLaird there is no reason really. Probably isn't much difference either way. Might prefer the way it looks with the cases. Practically, it may be useful if you want some cases to spill into each other.

Comment: This code smells bad, you have to read it carefuly to understand what is being achieve here, don't use a switch this way, use if statements instead!

Comment: For the most part, I just want it to work :) Either way, your solution does help. It looks like the problem is in my URL structure. When I submit a search with only one option select, the URL still contains each variable e.g. /?s=&StockType=&Make=CHEVROLET&Model=&post_type=vehicle

Comment: @user715564 try it with !empty() instead of isset(), that should work

Comment: several things come to mind.  The code with the `if` statements is shorter by several lines.  It's easier to read with `if`s because it's clearer what's intended.  It's also worth noting that the `switch` tests are equivalent to `==` rather than `===`, which may be important.

Comment: TonyArra, that actually doesn't work. It still only display results if and of the first dropbown selection box. If I only select the second or third dropdown, I get no results. If I select all three dropdowns I get all of the possible results returned.

Comment: @user715564 you're using !empty right...? I just tested that myself with your URL and the exact code from my answer, and it seems to work.

Comment: Yeah, I copied your exact code. So if my URL looks like this, /?s=&StockType=Type&Make=CHEVROLET&Model=Model&post_type=vehicle There will be no results that are shown.

Comment: If I format the case like this    case ( !empty($_GET['Make']) && $make != 'Make' ): I can then search each individual dropdown but I can't using combination. For example,I can't get results if an option is chosen on the first and second dropdown.

Comment: uh where did the make=make, model=model, type=type things come from? The URL you showed earlier had them blank if you didn't select them

Comment: I actually got it to working using an if statement. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use switch with true, it means that the only applicable case is the first one that evaluates to true or doesn't have a value!

What you want to do is something like:

```
switch($value){
    case 'value 1': 
        doSomething();
        break;
    case 'value 2': 
        doSomething();
        break;
    case 'value 3': 
        doSomething();
        break;
}
```

Look at the article on type juggling in PHP to understand your problem in a deeper manner: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 0):

yes It is always runs first case even if You rearrange case order then it will also run first case because your switch case coding is incorrect.
For ex. If user select third drop down then a value is set in **$model** and other variable set to **NULL** value but in your coding case it is always show to first case as **$stocktype** set to null but it is also satisfied the condition. According to my view you have to try:

```
if($_GET['stocktype']!=''){
$yourvalue=$_GET['stocktype'];
}
elseif($_GET['model']!=''){
$yourvalue=$_GET['model'];
}
elseif($_GET['make']!=''){
$yourvalue=$_GET['make'];
}
switch($yourvalue){
case 'stocktype':
//your code
break;
case 'make':
//your code
break;
case 'mode;':
//your code
break;
default:

}
```